# feedback() - not enough arguments

Tags: matlab, feedback

I need help creating a closed-loop system using unity feedback such that the system resembles the one in the image.

> [image: Closed loop system]

There are 4 states in the system and `K` is a 1x4 matrix. The open loop system is described by:

```
    %State-space model
A=[-0.231308504369119,0.0544096693079551,-0.000124548233093912,-0.990288665751696;0,0,1,0;-21.9913440608126,0,-4.27507057923922,1.16034911016267;11.8852437044909,0,-0.450303860814642,-0.711734908447950];
B=[-0.0109680172306510,0.0630660990762435;0,0;-32.2767539463422,5.44547987525456;-2.63365317966200,-7.15884612728451];
C=eye(4);
D=zeros(4,1);

% this is the cruise speed (TAS)
V = 180;
g0 = 9.81;


%% Open-loop response
% Check the eigenvalues. Note the bad damping of the Dutch roll and
% spiral modes
eigA = eig(A);

% Aileron control only. 
Ba = B(:,1);

% Create state-space system (open loop system, only aileron control), generate simulation output for a step input on
% the aileron
sa = ss(A, Ba, C, D);
```

I have tried:

```
feedback(K,-1*ones(1,4),-1)
```

but this doesn't work. I get the error:

> not enough input arguments

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the transfer function of Aircraft?

Comment: @SardarUsama I have updated the question to include the necessary system information.